# Can you convert a String to Int in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert a String into an int?

can u turn the String below into an int?

String string = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 603 174";

It would be ideal if each number be put in an int array.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(string.split(" ")[0]);` for first value. Change index for next values.

Comment: you mean convert it to 603174?

Comment: Obviously he doesn't. Read the last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

1. First split the String with `string.split(" ")` or `String.split("\\s+")` creating a String array.
2. Create an int array of the same size as the String array, or use an `ArrayList<Integer>`.
3. Next use a for loop to iterate through the String array generated
4. Call `Integer.parseInt(...)` on each item in the String array and use it to fill your int array or `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: +1 for NOT giving an actual coded solution to an obvious homework question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it use `string.split(" ");`. This will generate an array of Strings with all the numbers if they are separated by one space. And then you convert it one by one using `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class GenerateNumber {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String string = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 603 174";
        String[] items = string.split(" ");
        int[] numbers = new int[items.length];
        for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

Outputs: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 603, 174]

Answer (score -2):

You can write a pattern matcher to match a number in this case it would be [0-9]+ . then you can define a pattern matcher to extract each number and convert it to interger.

```
ArrayList<Integer> StringToInteger(String x)
{Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()){
       result.add(Intger.parseInt(m.group()));
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using all that for a simple split?